# A Counting Question on Combination and Permutation with Repetition

Tags: combinatorics

I've been working on this problem for a while now, and I am still not sure if the answer I got is correct. :) I assure that this is not a homework question, I am just not good at counting.

Say you need to select a 16-character password. Out of the 16 positions, 12 of them can be filled up with the 26 characters of the alphabet with repetition.The remaining 4 position can only be filled with 0 or 1. How many ways can you choose your 16 character password given the restrictions above?

Here's my answer:

$$26^{12 } \cdot 2^4 \cdot {{16} \choose 4}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: aww that's relieving, thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why, yes, that is okay.

There are 12 independent choices from 26 options, 4 independent choices from 2 options, and you may select any 4 places from the 16 in the string to position the digits.

So the count of distinct ways to do so is indeed: $26^{12} 2^4 \dbinom{16}{4}$ .